# Displaying a Live Preview of a Form while editing in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have developed a custom module which creates a specific `content type` in `Drupal` and allows users to add Images and some text. Now I want to add a preview section to my module for users to see the final out-put, the preview with real Images and text content while they are completing the form. I would like to know if this is possible to do Drupal and if so, what would be the best approach.

PS. I don't want to do any hacks and ruin the Drupal core.

Cheers!d

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to make this custom and might want to consider the Drupal ajax framework for this. There's a question [Adding AJAX to existing node form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25637/adding-ajax-to-existing-node-form) on **DrupalStackExchange** providing an answer for ajax use with the Drupal Form API.

In your custom module upon the custom code you already have, add `hook_form_alter()` to hook into your content type by`$form_id` and implement ajax on your form elements as the answer in the link describes. Then you can add a form field of type `markup` in which you render the form elements ajax callback output.

```
$form['live_preview'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $some_ajax_rendered_output,
);
```